# NSCompoundPredicate subpredicate order

Tags: objective-c, core-data

Does the order of the subpredicates in the array used to initialize an NSCompoundPredicate impact efficiency?

Example:

```
NSString * str = [self getAStr];
NSManagedObject * mo = [self getAMo];
NSString * fmt = @"(stringAttribute ==[cd] %@) AND (relationships CONTAINS %@)";
NSString * fmt2 = @"relationships.@count != 0";
NSPredicate * p1 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:fmt,str,mo];//expensive predicate
NSPredicate * p2 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:fmt2,nil];//less expensive predicate
NSCompoundPredicate * cp = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:@[p1,p2];
[self fetchSomethingWithPredicate:cp];
```

In the example above does the order of p1 and p2 change how the compound predicate is evaluated? Obviously evaluating p2 first would be more efficient, assuming p1 would be ignored if p2 evaluated to false.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the order of evaluation matters. Always put the most efficient and limiting predicates to the left - disqualify as many things as quickly as you can (though keep in mind that some predicates are really expensive).

If you break in the debugger and print out the 'cp' predicate, make sure that it's as efficient as possible, left to right.